# Role of up and down voting

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Some people have discussed in specific meta of site but I am asking here the center of every site.

I have seen a question which has good content but got down vote without any reason and one got up vote which is not closed by moderators. Or moderators are doing wrong, or maybe voters are doing wrong.
If person doesn't like a content personally and voting it down or a person think that this content is good for community and given up vote.

**What is the exact role of voting**

Comment: See [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @jonk it clearly says that voting should be for community not personally. But some users don't care for it.

Comment: Voting is and always will be down to the individual

Comment: Yes it is work of individual and content isn't.

Comment: There is no "right" and "wrong" when it comes to voting. You vote to express your opinion about the content. Is it clear? Useful? Does it show research effort? Is it likely to help someone else? Or not? Downvotes are intentionally disconnected from close votes, and your opinion of "good content" may not be the same as someone else's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **What is the exact role of voting**

The upvote and downvote buttons have tooltips!

Upvote:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

Downvote:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

The point is to have the community pitch in to indicate good or bad content.

Note that *popular* content doesn't mean it is on-topic, in such cases, it may get upvoted lots, but closed as it doesn't belong.